# Converse Truth Table

Tags: logic

I do not understand how the converse ($B \Rightarrow A$) truth table is logical.

For instance, take the statement, "If I am in Paris, then I am in France".

If I am in Paris, then I am in France. Therefore, $A \Rightarrow B$, since if I am in Paris, then I must also be in France. However, ($B \not \Rightarrow A$), since it can be true that I am in France, but that does not necessarily mean I am in Paris specifically.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me why my understanding is incorrect.

Thank you.

Comment: Im not sure that I understand what you are asking. Of course just because $A \implies B$, the converse doesn't have to be true. Where is the inconsistency?

Comment: The converse does not follow. You may be thinking of the contrapositive: If I am not in France, then I am not in Paris.

Comment: In my example, $A$ and $B$ are true. However, $B$ implies $A$ is false, since just because you're in France does not necessarily mean that you are in Paris. However, a converse truth table states that if $A$ and $B$ are true, then $B$ implies $A$ must also be true? This is where my confusion lies.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are already known to be true, then $A \Rightarrow B$ and also $B \Rightarrow A$, if it is only known that $A \Rightarrow B$, then $B \Rightarrow A$ doesn't follow necessarily. Also, I've never seen a "converse truth table", could you specify?

Comment: @JuliusL33t How can it be true that $B \implies A$? As I said, just because you are in France does not necessarily mean you are in Paris? So if $A$ and $B$ are both true, then how can it be true that $B \implies A$?

Comment: @The Pointer: If you already know that you are in Paris, then whatever $B$ might be, $B$ will still imply that you are in Paris, since you already know that you are in Paris. As you say, if you only know that IF you are in Paris THEN you are in France, then it does not follow that just because you are in France, you must be in Paris. Clearer?

Comment: The statements $ (A\implies B)$ and $ (B\implies A)$ are both true if and only if *both* $A$ and $B$ are true. To be equivalent the statements would have to be true irrespective of the truth values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @The Pointer: Maybe this is the confusion: There are three things here, the truth of $A$, the truth of $B$ and the truth of $A \Rightarrow B$. If you know that $A \Rightarrow B$, then you can neither conclude $A$ nor $B$, all you can say is "if $A$ then $B$", which is different from claiming either $A$ or $B$. Just because you know that IF you are in Paris THEN you are in France doesn't mean that you are either in Paris or in France.

Comment: @JuliusL33t Forget about $A \implies B$. If we only know that $A$ and $B$ are true, then how is it logical that $B \implies A$? Or is it necessary to first find $A \implies B$ before $B \implies A$? That might be where my confusion lies.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing the word "Converse" with "Contrapositive"  As is already mentioned $A\implies B$ does not imply $B\implies A$ (*the converse*).  However $A\implies B$ **does** imply $\neg B\implies \neg A$ (*the contrapositive*).  If I am in Paris then I am in France.  If I am not in France then I am not in Paris.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales $(A\implies B) \land (B\implies A)$ is the same as $A\iff B$, which can hold if both $A$ and $B$ are false.

Comment: @ThePointer: How about this: If you know $A$: "You are in Paris", then:
"You are in China $\Rightarrow$ You are in Paris"
and 
"You are in the US $\Rightarrow$ You are in Paris"
and
"You are a little green alien $\Rightarrow$ You are in Paris"
and certainly: 
"You are in France $\Rightarrow$ You are in Paris".
All of this is usually stated as "$A \Rightarrow T$" is true regardless of what "$A$" is. But ONLY if you know that you really are in Paris. Knowing that $B$ is true doesnt change $B \Rightarrow A$ if $A$ is already true.

Comment: @JuliusL33t I am told that $A$ and $B$ are true. I am then asked to find if $B$ implies $A$. My textbook says that $B \implies A$ is true. However, if we substitute my statement about Paris and France, the book's answer makes no sense: being in France does not imply being in Paris. Therefore, how can It be true that $B \implies A$?

Comment: @ThePointer: No, if $A$ is known to be true, i.e, it is known that you are in Paris, then it makes perfect sense that "You are in France $\Rightarrow$ you are in Paris", Being in France DOES imply that you are in Paris, if you already know you're in Paris. See Chas Browns comment to your comment in his answer. It's exactly the same principle.

Comment: Just to finish it off: And of course, just as Chas Brown states. not being in France will ALSO imply that you are in Paris, if you already know you're in Paris. But I can agree that it can be a little mind-bendy if you're not used to it.

Comment: @JuliusL33t In that case, $A$ is true and $B$ is false, but $B \implies A$ is still true?

Comment: @ThePointer: Yes, thats correct. But note that if $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $A \Rightarrow B$ is FALSE.

Comment: @JuliusL33t This is very illuminating. Thank you!

Comment: @florence You are absolutely correct. I don't know why I added the 'only if' part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's agree that 'if you are in Paris, then you are in France' ($A \implies B$). (We could get picky, and say maybe you're in Paris, Texas; but let's not!).

But then the **converse** ($B \implies A$) is not automatically true: for example, we can't then deduce from 'if you are in Paris, then you are in France' that 'if you are in France, then you are in Paris'. In that sense you're right that 'it's not logical' to say the converse is always true.

Now, bear in mind that the converse *might* be true, or it *might not*. It must be proven either way based on other information. And it turns out that we know enough other things, about European geography in this case, that we can also *prove* that the converse is not true.

On the other hand, what we can *always* deduce is called the **contrapositive**: once we accept the truth of 'if you are in Paris, then you are in France', then we always automatically can say 'if you are *not* in France, then you are *not* in Paris' ($\neg B \implies \neg A$). That will always be true (at least, in the world of mathematical language).

Comment: So is my textbook incorrect in saying that if $A$ and $B$ are true, then $B \implies A$ is true? That's what it says in the truth table. But if we then substitute the Paris and France statement, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Suppose it's raining right now; and I tell you 'if I have an odd number of coins in my pocket, it's raining right now'. Is that a true statement? Does it really matter how many coins I have in my pocket? You're right that it's not particularly *helpful* of me to make that statement; but it's still a true statement.

Comment: Well, that would be a bit silly to put it that way. What matters is that if you ALREADY KNOW the conclusion is true (e.g., that it is raining) it doesn't matter whether the premise itself is actually true or false; in either case it is raining. However if we DON'T KNOW the conclusion is true, what we are being told is that IF we know the premise is true THEN the we know the conclusion is true; and that is useful.

Comment: Your comment is illuminating. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. It takes a bit of practice to wrap you're head around the difference between conversational logic and mathematical logic :).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let's assume you have a number,for example 5. When you are asked 5 is in which circle you will say it is in B. Then by this statement one can say your number is also in A.

But lets assume you have number 3. And you are asked in which circle number is? You day it is in circle A. So one can't say the number is in B!

This case is same , assume circle B as Paris and fields A as France and see your statement.